# How to obtain uncertainty estimate around MLE parameters based on KL-Divergence?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, kullback-leibler, uncertainty

Suppose I know some true distribution $S(x)$, and I have a method of approximating $S$ based on a transformation of another distribution $G(x|\theta)$. We denote the approximation as $S^*(x|\theta)$. The context is from [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.idm.2020.10.009).

From a few sources [[e.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Relation_to_minimizing_Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence_and_cross_entropy)], we know that minimizing the KL-Divergence between $S(x)$ and $S^*(x|\theta)$ gives the maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) of $\theta$. However, now I'm interested in estimating the uncertainty in $\theta$. In my case, $G(x|\theta)$ is a gamma PDF and so $\theta$ has 2 parameters. So the question is:

**Is there any way to characterize the joint likelihood distribution of $\theta$ based on $S(x)$ and $S^*(x|\theta)$ alone?**

Let's assume we have no prior on $\theta$, unless that makes it harder ...

I'm imagining sampling various values of $\theta$ and computing the KL-Divergence, but I'm not sure what relationship the distribution $D_{KL}\big(S(x) ~||~ S^*(x|\theta)\big)$ over $\theta$ has with the likelihood distribution of $\theta$.

Comment: Actually, I may have figured it out.  Since the likelihood of $\theta$ is defined as $E_S[log(S^*(x|\theta))] = E_S[log(S(x))] - D_{KL}(S(x)~||~S^*(x|\theta))$, to define the likelihood based on the $D_{KL}$, we can simply add back the term $E_S[log(S(x))]$ ( a constant w.r.t. $\theta$), from which we can estimate the uncertainty, etc... I think...?